# How many implication graphs are there for a given number of literals?

Tags: logic, graph-theory, computer-science, propositional-calculus

The context here is [implication graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implication_graph) over propositional literals and the [2-SAT problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-satisfiability). What function describes the possible number of non-redundant implication graphs given the number of literals? What I'm also trying to do is compare this quantity to the number of total graphs over the same number of literals.

Comment: What makes an implication graph redundant?

Comment: @MishaLavrov: if it's easier to answer the question without considering redundancies, I'll take that answer. But an implication graph like $a \rightarrow a \rightarrow a \rightarrow a \rightarrow a$ seems pretty redundant.

Comment: But do you have a formal definition of redundant?

Comment: @ManuelLafond: Thanks for asking. Let's try this as a formal definition of redundant. Given two literals $\alpha$ and $\beta$, an implication graph $G$ is _redundant_ if there is more than one occurrence of the implication $\alpha \rightarrow \beta$ in $G$. This is to capture the underlying situation in 2-SAT where the same clause occurs more than once.

Comment: OK then.  So is it true that if you have $n$ variables and so $2n$ literals, then there are $2 \cdot {2n \choose 2} - 2n$ possible directed edges (the $-2n$ to remove implications of the type $x \rightarrow \neg x$)?  Then there'd be $2^{2 \cdot {2n \choose 2} - 2n}$ possible implication graphs.